# Classification of a linear system of equations with a parameter

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to get every possible value of `k` that returns infinite number of solutions or no solution to this system:

```
k x1 + x2 + x3 == 1
x1 + k x2 + x3 == 1
x1 + x2 + k x3 == 1
```

How do I tell *Mathematica* to do it?

Comment: `mat = {{k , 1, 1}, {1, k, 1}, {1, 1, k}}; b = {1, 1, 1}; LinearSolve[mat, b]` gives the solution `{1/(2 + k), 1/(2 + k), 1/(2 + k)}` , so just plugin the `k` of interest to get any solution you want. For each `k` there is another solution. Is this what you mean?

Comment: what i need is the possible values of k so that the matrix returns infinite solutions and the possible values of k so that the matrix returns no solution

Comment: Then may be `Solve[Det[mat] == 0, k]`, gives `{{k -> -2}, {k -> 1}, {k -> 1}}` so any of these values of `k` will make `A` singular. No solution.

Comment: This may be [homework](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33561/system-of-equations-how-to-get-the-values-of-a-variable-for-infinite-and-no-sol/33570#33570), for which the instructor expects the student to work it out from the documentation.

Comment: @XTN Welcome to `mathematica.se`. Consider registering your account so that you'll be able to interact better with this site.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading appropriately the result of `Reduce` (in the following we are treating `k` as a parameter):

```
Reduce[{ k x + y + z == 1, x + k y + z == 1, x + y + k z == 1}, {x, y, z}] //
TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Now we can enumerate the following cases :

---

### I) **`k == 1`**

There are infinitely many solutions `{ x, y, z}` restricted by this formula `z == - x - y + 1`. Then the matrix `m`:

```
m = {{k, 1, 1}, {1, k, 1}, {1, 1, k}};
```

satisfies:

```
    Through @ { MatrixRank, NullSpace}[ m /. k -> 1]
```

> ```
> { 1, {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}}}
> ```

i.e the rank of `m` is `1` and its null space is two-dimensional and spanned by vectors `{-1, 0, 1}` and  `{-1, 1, 0}`.

---

### II) `k != 1` and `k != -2`

There is only one solution given by this formula `x == 1/(2 + k) && y == x && z == 1 - k x - y`. Using the option `Backsubstitution -> True` in `Reduce` we get the solutions explicitly: `(-1 + k) (2 + k) != 0 && x == 1/(2 + k) && y == 1/(2 + k) && 
 z == 1/(2 + k)`.

e.g. for `k == 2`

```
    Through @ { MatrixRank, NullSpace}[ m /. k -> 2]
```

> ```
>  { 3, {}}
> ```

When the matrix `m` is not singular we have zero-dimensional null space and exactly one solution.

---

### III)  `k == -2`

`Reduce` tell us that there are no solutions. See e.g.  `Det[m /. k -> -2]` or just
`Reduce[{-2 x + y + z == 1, x - 2 y + z == 1, x + y - 2 z == 1}, {x, y, z}]`.

```
    Through @ { MatrixRank, NullSpace}[ m /. k -> -2]
```

> ```
> { 2, {{1, 1, 1}}}
> ```

( see  the Kronecker–Capelli theorem called also Rouché–Capelli etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is not a *Mathematica* but a *mathematics* question. To be specific, a linear algebra question. What you have is a coefficient matrix

```
A = {{k, 1, 1},{1, k, 1},{1, 1, 1 k}}
```

and you try to classify the solutions of

$$A (x_1,x_2,x_3)^\top=(1,1,1)^\top.$$

If you really have no idea, then I would go with Artes solution, which can be written more concise in matrix form

```
Reduce[A.{x, y, z} == {1, 1, 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

I strongly recommend that you review your lecture notes about linear algebra and *then* try use your knowledge in *Mathematica*. To be specific, look at the [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eigenvalues.html) of your coefficient matrix

```
Eigenvalues[A]

(* {-1 + k, -1 + k, 2 + k} *)
```

Since the determinant is the product of these 3 numbers, you can instantly see that you can make the determinant zero by choosing `k=1` or `k=-2`. You will find of course the same result when you use the determinant directly and calculate its roots

```
d = Det[A]
(* 2 - 3 k + k^3 *)

Solve[d == 0, k]
(* {{k -> -2}, {k -> 1}, {k -> 1}} *)
```

To classify your solutions, you can calculate the general solution

```
LinearSolve[A, {1, 1, 1}]
```

or you can even use

```
Solve[A.{x, y, z} == {1, 1, 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

and observe what happens if you insert the values for `k` which make the system singular.