# Simultaneous equations—classify the solution set as finite, infinite, or none

Tags: equation-solving

How do I find the values of $b$ and $c$ for the equations $x + 5 y = 4$ and $2 x + by = c$ with a unique solution, an infinite set of solutions and no solutions with *Mathematica*?

Comment: @JasonB I have tried using the 'solve' and 'piecewise' functions, but the inputs end up being long/convoluted... I was curious as to whether there was an easier option. (I am new to mathematica, so I am sorry if this question is silly!)

Comment: Not really sure about this one.  By inspection, it's clear that setting `{b,c}` to `{10,8}` is a solution, but I can't figure out how to get Mathematica to spit this answer out.

Comment: `Reduce[{x + 5 y == 4, 2 x + b y == c}, {b, c}]` gives something, but not what I was looking for.

Comment: @JasonB Thank you for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classification of a linear system of equations with a parameter](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33561/classification-of-a-linear-system-of-equations-with-a-parameter). Closely related [General form of a linear transformation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37172/general-form-of-a-linear-transformation)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @m_goldberg I disagree with the new title, I have the feeling that the original title was correct, since the OP was explicitly interested differentiating between the cases and not on the complete solution set.

Comment: @MauricioLobos. Acting on your criticism, I have come up with a new and hopefully improved title. Should this not satisfy you, it's your turn to write a new title.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for accepting the request. The new title is very appropriate and points nicely to the duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

The quickest way to get there is to first `Solve` the first equation for `x` or `y`, then use `Reduce` on the second equation for the other variable:

```
Reduce[
 2*x + b*y == c /. Solve[x + 5*y == 4, y],
 x]
```

[image]

So either `b=10`, which makes `c=8`, or else `c` and `b` depend on the value of `x`.

It's interesting the different outputs you get depending on which variables you reduce by (thanks to Eric Towers for the tip on `Backsubstitution`)

```
DeleteDuplicates[
 LogicalExpand@
    Reduce[{x + 5 y == 4, 2 x + b y == c}, #, 
     Backsubstitution -> True] & /@ Permutations[{b, c, x, y}]
 ]
```

[image]

It's clear from these that `b=10` and `c=8` are the only solutions that are valid *for all x and y*.  Is there a way to specify that you want the solution in this case?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, Jason! :) Your effort is very much appreciated.

Comment: "BackSubstitution -> True" will make it clearer that "y == (4 - x)/5)" in the second disjunction of your first `Reduce[]` is actually "y == (-8 + c)/(-10 + b)".

Answer (score 5):

I think this is somehow a problem from the perspective that Mathematica will NOT teach you math, it will help you computing stuff in several cases. You have to be able to interpret the output with your math understanding.

Your equations can be solved by

```
eqs = {
   x + 5*y == 4
   , 2*x + b*y == c
   };
vars = {x, y};
sol = Solve[eqs, vars]
```

[image: solution]

Here Mathematica gave you the answer assuming that `-10 + b` will not be zero, although we never gave that information.

From your math class you should know how to differentiate between the cases. So if you solve first, e.g., in the first equation for `x`

```
solx = Solve[eqs[[1]], x][[1]]
```

[image: solx]

and put this in the second equation

```
eqs[[2]] /. solx[[1]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: equation]

you can clearly see, that if `b` equals 10 and `c` equals 8, then `y` can be anything, so you get an infinite number of solutions. But if `b` equals 10 and `c` is not specified or something like `c==3`, then this equations can not be fulfilled in general, so you dont get any solution (you can identify this cases in the solution given above in `sol` but Mathematica will not tell you that). You can check this as follows

```
Solve[eqs /. {b -> 10}, vars]
Solve[eqs /. {c -> 8, b -> 10}, vars]
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use

```
Reduce[eqs, vars]
```

[image: reduce]

but you have to be able to interpret this output by yourself, i.e., for the first case you get an infinite number of solutions for `x` and `y` (since they depend on each other) and for the second case you a specific `x` and then a specific `y`. If none of these cases are fulfilled, e.g., `b==10` and `c==3`, then you dont have a solution.

**My point is that Mathematica will NOT teach you math, in several cases you have to be able to interpret the output and know that may be Mathematica itself made some assumptions on its own (see the output of `sol`).**

Comment: Thank you - To clarify, I can do the question by hand. I was more curious as to whether there was an option to obtain and present the answer on mathematica.

Comment: Hmmm .... the best thing you will get from Mathematica is for this case with `Reduce`, as already pointed out by Jason B, since it gives you the cases under which you get solutions. But an interpretation by the user is still necessary.

Comment: I see - Thank you for the help! Very much appreciated.